# Why does leading zero impact the comparison when I take the parameter from the body instead of the query in ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on making a calendar API using **ASP.NET Core Web API** and a local database from MS SQL Server as my database. I have created an API that takes day, month and year as input and returns the corresponding day. The code being -

```
        public async Task<List<DayParameter>> GetDayByDate(Day RequestParameter)
        {
            using (var connection = _context.CreateConnection())
            {
                var days = await connection.QueryAsync<DayParameter>(
                    "sp_getDay", // Stored procedure name
                    param: new
                    {
                        RequestParameter.date,
                        RequestParameter.month,
                        RequestParameter.year
                    },
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure // Specify that it's a stored procedure
                );

                return days.ToList();
            }
        }
```

> My Day.cs file is -

```
    public class Day
    {
        public int date { get; set; }
        public int month { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
    }
```

As far as I know, by default, the **`RequestParameter`** is passed in the body of the HTTP request. When I pass **`day`** and/or **`month`** from body as **int** with a digit with leading zeroes  *i.e 01, 02, 03, etc*  then the API wouldn't even hit it gives the following error -

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-d482f86081879283daasa2qpq0314-00",
  "errors": {
    "day": [
      "The day field is required."
    ],
    "$.month": [
      "Invalid leading zero before '4'. Path: $.month | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 12."
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I add the **`[FromQuery]`** attribute in the action method, then everything seems to work fine.

> The working code is -

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("getdaybydate")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetDayByDate([FromQuery] Day day)
        {
            var _list = await this.repo.GetDayByDate(day);
            if (_list != null)
            {
                return Ok(_list);
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
```

> The response for this API is -

```
[
  {
    "date": "1 January 2024",
    "day": "Monday"
  }
]
```

Can anybody explain what's going on here?

I was working on an ASP.NET Core Web API project and I encountered an issue regarding the comparison of passing parameters of the API. I expected the code to work fine on both scenarios *i.e without any attribute and by using [FromBody] attribute*, but the result was not the same.

Comment: Show us how you send the day value. And not recommend using this way to send the date. What about if the user sends the date with values: `date: 32, month: 13: year: -2023`. And I don't see that you have the validation for the received value. The correct way will be to receive the date value in date (string) or ISO8601 format, then you can extract the day, month, year via `date.Day`, `date.Month`, `date.Year`.

Comment: Show the full request where you are sending the date in the body.

Comment: _"As far as I know, by default, the RequestParameter is passed in the body of the HTTP request"_ It depends. GET requests aren't technically allowed to use request body. Can you show us the actual request.

Comment: The request is - 

```{
  "date": 01,
  "month": 01,
  "year": 2024
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how do you pass the JSON data, but if you use Postman/Swagger, it does not provide a built-in way to specify that leading zeros are allowed for numeric fields. That is to say you need to pass the JSON string like below:

```
{
    "date": "01",
    "month": "01",
    "year": 2024 
}
```

If you are passing the JSON like above but the code still doesn't work then, you can explicitly add a custom JsonConverter to allow leading zeros before numbers like below:

```
public class LeadingZeroNumberConverter : JsonConverter<int>
{
    public override int Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(reader.GetString(), out int intValue))
            {
                return intValue;
            }
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number)
        {
            if (reader.TryGetInt32(out int intValue))
            {
                return intValue;
            }
        }

        throw new JsonException($"Invalid leading zero before number: {reader.GetString()}");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, int value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteNumberValue(value);
    }
}
```

Register the custom JsonConverter:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new LeadingZeroNumberConverter());
});
```

Comment: Could you help me with the implementation of this class in your answer? Where do I have to use it? Sorry if this is a bad question, I'm new in programming.

Comment: Hi @AbhijeetPS, 1.create the LeadingZeroNumberConverter class which extends the  `System.Text.Json.JsonConverter<int>` in any location in your project. 2.Register the class in Program.cs(if you use .net core version beyond .NET 6) or register in the Startup.cs. 3.Then when you post the JSON data, it will hit this custom converter by default. Be sure you need pass the JSON with `"01"` instead of `01`.

Comment: Hi @AbhijeetPS, any update here?

Comment: Hi, @Rena Thank you, your answer helped me solve my problem.